# Martingale and Ito lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I notice that there is a lemma: $d(XY)=XdY+YdX+d[X,Y]$ and $XY-[X,Y]$ is a martingale. I wonder how to show that $XY-[X,Y]$ is a martingale? And it is true that $[X,Y]=0$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: What kind of random variables are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are diffusion process. There is nothing tricky here. All are from intro level of stochastic calculus.

Comment: Usually the quadratic variation is defined as the unique adapted, right-continuous, non-decreasing process starting in zero that makes $X^2 - [X]$ a local martingale. Showing that such a process actually exists is a rather lengthy exercise. The quadratic covariation is then defined as $[X,Y] = \frac{1}{4}\left( [X+Y] - [X-Y] \right)$, from which it follows that $[X,Y]$ is exactly the process making $XY-[X,Y]$ a local martingale.